# Combining multiple widget components into one module

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on authentication for my react project and my current file structure looks like so

```
-components
 -auth
   AuthContainer.jsx
   ForgotWidget.jsx
   LoginWidget.jsx
   SignUpWidget.jsx
```

Then I call the component in my header file via `<LoginWidget />`

What is the best practice of combining these all together so I can just call it like  instead of calling each individual?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a wrapper component that decides which component to render based on a specific prop. Your `AuthContainer` actually looks suitable for that.

Maybe you can do something like `<AuthContainer widget="login" />` or `<AuthContainer widget="forgot" />` then.

In your `AuthContainer` you'd have a control flow like:

```
const {widget} = this.props;
switch (widget) {
  case 'login': return <LoginWidget />;
  case 'forgot': return <ForgotWidget />;
  ..
}
```

Maybe that `widget` could also be an internal state of the container if it is in charge of all the controls that allow the user to switch between the views.